# Issues while writing to Excelsheet using java apache POI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-poi, java-io

I have two queries as below :-

**1)** Below is my code to find the **total disk space, free and used disk space in my local machine**. I want to export these values in a newly created excel sheet under three columns **Total Disk Space, Free DiskSpace** and **UsedDiskSpace**.

But in my below code I am able to a create excel sheet under C:\ location but I am not able to set the values of my excel sheet columns to the ones calculated and stored under Total diskspace, FreeDiskSpace and UsedDiskSpace variables. Can anyone suggest me how can I modify my below code to set the excel sheet column values to capacity,Free space and used space variable values etc.

**2)** How can I convert this code into a .bat executable file so that it can be executed on double click and there is no need to execute the entire code through IDE. Some examples will help!!

```
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import java.io.IOException;   
import org.apache.commons.io.FileSystemUtils; 
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;   
import org.apache.commons.io.FileSystemUtils;    
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DiskSpace 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  try{ String filename="C:/NewExcelFile.xls" ;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");  
        ArrayList alldisk=null;
        alldisk=new ArrayList();
        alldisk.add("C:");


        File drive=null;
        long capacity=0,freespace=0, usedspace=0; 
        for(int i=0;i<alldisk.size();i++)
        {
           drive = new File(alldisk.get(i).toString());
           capacity = drive.getTotalSpace(); 
           freespace = drive.getFreeSpace(); 
           usedspace = capacity - freespace;
           HSSFRow rowhead= sheet.createRow((short)0);
            rowhead.getCell(1).setCellValue(capacity);
            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(capacity);
            rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(freespace);
            rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(usedspace);
            FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(filename);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        }} catch ( Exception ex ) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        }
           }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
rowhead.getCell(1).setCellValue(capacity);
```

line.It gives NullPointerException error and don't use createCell(short) it is deprecated method so please remove short type cast.

Here is my code

```
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import java.io.IOException;   
import org.apache.commons.io.FileSystemUtils; 
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;   
import org.apache.commons.io.FileSystemUtils;    
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DiskSpace 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  try{ String filename="/home/likewise-open/EZDI-DOMAIN/cshah/Desktop/NewExamle.xls" ;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");  
        ArrayList alldisk=null;
        alldisk=new ArrayList();
        alldisk.add("/home/likewise-open/EZDI-DOMAIN/cshah/Desktop");


        File drive=null;
        long capacity=0,freespace=0, usedspace=0; 
        for(int i=0;i<alldisk.size();i++)
        {
           drive = new File(alldisk.get(i).toString());
           capacity = drive.getTotalSpace(); 
           freespace = drive.getFreeSpace(); 
           usedspace = capacity - freespace;
           HSSFRow rowhead= sheet.createRow((short)i);
            //rowhead.getCell(1).setCellValue(capacity);
            rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue(capacity);
            rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue(freespace);
            rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue(usedspace);

        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(filename);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();} catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
           }}
```

Comment: Still it is not working..See if it is working at your end in any-other approach for my code.

Comment: Instead of this System.out.println(ex) use  ex.printStackTrace();.So that you can know error and the trace from where error is generated.

Comment: Can you paste the entire modified code you are using? I will check in my PC if i am missing something at my end.

Comment: When I used your code I am getting some values in my excel sheet but it is in a very different format 5.00106E+11, 4.31212E+11, 68893417472.00. How can I handle this in the code or exel sheet to get correct values as my values expected is: Total disk= 465GB used = 61GB and free is 404 GB. If you can see in the code the conversion to GB is done but in excel sheet some different values are coming.

Comment: capacity and all are long value.and its length is too long that's why excel has converted it into exponential form.Explicitly you have to convert that long value to GB or MB.Make column width such that the whole value is printed.

Comment: ya I added it in this way and it is working. Problem solved long C = capacity/(1024*1024) and then pass this value in the excelsheet column it will solve the problem